# How can I add 10px to a div's left coordinate?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering how I can add 10px to a div's current left position. Here is the code:

```
  <div id="ok" style="width:56px; height:56px; background:blue; color:white; position:absolute; top:5px; left:5px; z-index:8;">Hello</div>
```

I want to add an extra 10px to the left of the position absolute div using javascript, so the code would essentially look like this. Here is the code:

```
  <div id="ok" style="width:56px; height:56px; background:blue; color:white; position:absolute; top:5px; left:15px; z-index:8;">Hello</div>
```

How can I add an extra 10 to the left of my div using javascript?

Answer (score 2):

If you are free to use JavaScript,

```
var elm = document.getElementById("ok")
elm.style.left = (parseFloat(elm.style.left) + 10) + "px";
```

Its basically the same amount of code, and faster since it uses native methods.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TmZ8c/)**

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery it is rather easy to do using callback function as a second argument of `css` method:

```
$('#ok').css('left', function(i, val) {
    return parseInt(val, 10) + 10;
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/z6j8a/